# auto run commands in separate terminal windows

Tags: command-line

I have three commands that i want to run in a sequence but in three separate terminal windows after boot up.

currently, I open first window,run the command and then run another  terminal window, run a command and then finally the third terminal window and run the final command on it.

since, i have to wait for the process to complete after each command, the second and third window should open after, let us say 1 minute wait.

is there a way to run this using an auto run batch process after boot? many thanks.
 marc

Answer (score 0):

You can set `cron` to run a script/command during system startup

make the below entry in `crontab -e`

```
@reboot <path to script file/command>
```

You can also give multiple commands they will run in sequence

```
@reboot firstCommand;secondCommand;thirdCommand
```

Comment: QQ. will my command execute in three different terminal windows? after execution, these terminal windows should remain open. if one of them closes, then the dependent processes would stop.

Comment: No, It will run in same terminal once a command will complete and exit other command will start executing.
If your command will keep running occupying the shell then the next command will not run.

Comment: ok. thanks. I am looking for a solution where commands can execute in three new terminal windows one after the other and windows remain open after command execution.

Comment: You can also set multiple `cron` with `@reboot` statement if sequence is not important 
for example: 
`@reboot firstCommand` 

`@reboot secondCommand` 

`@reboot thirdCommand`